# How to integrate Spring roles in gwt application

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security

I'm working on GWT application and I have followed this tutorial (http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) to do authentication. 
Now I need to handle roles, for example ROLE_USER can to see some GWT widget or he can execute some method. I saw that in `spring-security.xml` it is possible to handle roles basing them on url pattern but it isn't my case.
Can somebody help me with example code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be ablet o use the `Spring Roles` directly in your `GWT` application.

You probabably have to role your own security mechanisms on the `GWT` side, which includes following steps:

1. Transmit the `Spring roles` for the corresponding user from your `Spring` backend to your `GWT` frontend (using `RequestFactory`, `RequestBuilder`, `RPC` or `dynamic host page`)
2. If you use an `MVP` framework (i.e. `GWTP`) it might support authorization out of the box (for example `GWTP` has [Gatekeepers](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-Gatekeeper) that provides authorization support for `Presenters`) or you will have to role your own `authorization` framework. AFAIK there is [UiBinderAutho](http://ziedhamdi.github.io/UiBinderAutho/) which supports authorization of a widget level).

**One import thing: NEVER TRUST THE CLIENT**

That means you should always do authorization also on the backend side (`Spring`).